# Automated PDF extraction - Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, pdf, extract

I've inherited a program that runs daily as a scheduled task that takes a single 400ish page PDF of patient data reports and splits it up into individual patient accounts.  Then once it is split up it queues each of the files for upload into a file repository.

Normally it runs totally without any human interaction but today it has started crashing on a page of the PDF spilt, in this case pg 91-92.  So I extracted and deleted those two pages completely from the main PDF.  Re-ran the program, and it crashed earlier than before at pages 87-88.

I'm pretty well stumped here.

This is the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length 
at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolen fAlwaysCopy)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at _24HrSumm.Program.validRoom(String strRoom)
at _24HrSumm.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I am totally not to be confused with a programmer, I've been looking through the PDF itself trying to see what is hanging up this program, based on what I read through the code in Visual Studio, but I can't find a invalid Room number, which is what I assume is crashing the program.  Am I just totally off?

Thanks just for reading and for any ideas or help!

Comment: This error means that the programmer who created this program is calling the function SubString( startIndex, length) on a string that is shorter than startIndex + length. If you are not a programmer you will need to contact one to fix this for you.

Comment: I did find a section of code that looks like this:

static bool validRoom(string strRoom)
        {
            bool blnReturn = false;

            if (strRoom.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "icu")
            {
                return true;


Could that be the cause?  I just can't find anything different between this PDF extraction that is failing and any of the ones from past days that did not fail.

Comment: If for some reason you run into an empty strRoom (strRoom == "") then you will get this error. Put this instead:  if (strRoom.Length >=3 && strRoom.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "icu").Please be aware that this might just postpone the error and it may crash somewhere else. I still recommend you to find a programmer that can fix this for you properly.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Awesome, thank you so much!  That former programmer is out of town but I will get him to review it ASAP!